# Qual a melhor tag para criar uma barra de menu

Tags: html5, css3

Boa noite pessoal, sou iniciante e tals, venho pedir ajuda para criar uma barra de menu

Estou montando um site e tenho 2 barras horizontais, a primeira eu quero colocar uma barra, com um botão de pesquisa e outro de login/cadastro

Já em baixo são os menus de navegação.

Geralmente crio uma tag e coloco um bg color nelas para fazer uma barra, e tenho extrema dificuldade para posicionar da forma que desejo

Alguém saberia me indicar o que fazer para posicionar perfeitamente está barra, além de uma tags adequada para cria-la?

Valeu pessoal!

Comment: Dê uma lida nisso: [MDN: nav](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav). Sobre o resto, sugiro [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [EMCV](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você pode fazer seu menu desta forma na horizontal

```css
  *{margin: 0; padding: 0;}
  body{font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;}
  .menu{height: 60px; width: 100%; background-color: #f74343; display: table;}
  .menu ul{list-style: none;}
  .menu ul li{float: left;}
  .menu ul li a{text-decoration: none; color: #fff; padding: 20.8px; float: left; font-weight: lighter;}
  .menu ul li a:hover{background-color: #f77d7d; transition: 0.5s;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Página Inicial</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Loja</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Suporte</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

você pode usar a tag **nav** ele representa uma seleção de links
ex:

```html
    <nav>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
```

não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, você quer uma tag pra posicionar melhor seu menu?